# average number of characters per word in a list

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I'm new to python and i need to calculate the  average number of characters per word in a list

using these definitions and helper function `clean_up`.

a token is a str that you get from calling the string method split on a line of a file.

a  word is a non-empty token from the file that isn't completely made up of punctuation.
find the "words" in a file by using `str.split` to find the tokens and then removing the punctuation from the words using the helper function `clean_up`.

A sentence is a sequence of characters that is terminated by (but doesn't include) the characters `!`, `?`, `.` or the end of the file, excludes whitespace on either end, and is not empty.

This is my homework question from my computer science class in my college

the clean up function is:

```
def clean_up(s):
    punctuation = """!"',;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\"""
    result = s.lower().strip(punctuation)
    return result
```

my code is:

```
def average_word_length(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and at
    least one str in text contains more than just \n.

    Return the average length of all words in text. Surrounding punctuation
    is not counted as part of the words. 


    >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul and Mary\n']
    >>> average_word_length(text)
    5.142857142857143 
    """

    for ch in text:
        word = ch.split()
        clean = clean_up(ch)
        average = len(clean) / len(word)
    return average
```

I get 5.0, but i am really confused, some help would be greatly appreciated :) 
PS I'm using python 3

Comment: you want to `float(len(word))`

Comment: @Hoopdady OP is using Python3.

Comment: This only gives average of the last item in the input

Comment: `yield average` inside the `for` loop would make for a nice generator.

Comment: oh neat, didn't know python3 didn't do integer division. Oh yeah, and just caught that the average was inside the loop.

Comment: @Hoopdady yep, that's why `from __future__ import division` works in Python2. Python3 is the future!!! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's clean up some of these functions with imports and generator expressions, shall we?

```
import string

def clean_up(s):
    # I'm assuming you REQUIRE this function as per your assignment
    # otherwise, just substitute str.strip(string.punctuation) anywhere
    # you'd otherwise call clean_up(str)
    return s.strip(string.punctuation)

def average_word_length(text):
    total_length = sum(len(clean_up(word)) for sentence in text for word in sentence.split())
    num_words = sum(len(sentence.split()) for sentence in text)
    return total_length/num_words
```

You may notice this actually condenses to a length and unreadable one-liner:

```
average = sum(len(word.strip(string.punctuation)) for sentence in text for word in sentence.split()) / sum(len(sentence.split()) for sentence in text)
```

It's gross and disgusting, which is why you shouldn't do it ;). Readability counts and all that.

Answer (score 5):

This is a short and sweet method to solve your problem that is still readable.

```
def clean_up(word, punctuation="!\"',;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\\"):
    return word.lower().strip(punctuation)  # you don't really need ".lower()"

def average_word_length(text):
    cleaned_words = [clean_up(w) for w in (w for l in text for w in l.split())]
    return sum(map(len, cleaned_words))/len(cleaned_words)  # Python2 use float

>>> average_word_length(['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul and Mary\n'])
5.142857142857143
```

Burden of all those preconditions falls to you.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Or a list-comprehension. :)